# Нажатие клавиш в Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я хочу эмитировать нажатия клавиш, а так же ввода текста. Немного погуглив я нашел следующие модули:

- win_keyboard (модуль был удален)
- node-key-sender (использует Java, нет возможности использовать русские буквы)
- kbm-robot (использует Java)
- RobotJS (использует Python)

То есть у них есть проблемы с русскими символами. Что можно использовать вместо них?
Нужно избежать зависимости от Java, Python, а так же иметь поддержку русского текста.

---

Попытка использовать nut.js

```js
const { keyboard, Key, mouse, left, right, up, down, screen } = require("@nut-tree/nut-js");

setTimeout(() =>
{
    console.log('Пишем текст');
    keyboard.type("русский текст");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Может, https://github.com/nut-tree/nut.js ? Судя по докам, зависимость от Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.

Comment: Я получил ошибку при установке, добавил ее в вопрос.

Comment: @OliverPatterson может [вот это](https://github.com/nut-tree/nut.js#windows) не установлено?

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, к сожалению нет. У меня было установлено 2005-2013, я докачал еще 2051-2019, но это не помогло.

Comment: robotjs и https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook. в этой задаче избежать зависимости от питона не получится никогда (если, конечно, это не будет запуск в контексте electron-приложения)

Comment: Вот тут пишут, что нужно учитывать версию Node.js и npm. Посмотрите, может, какой-то из случаев ваш: https://github.com/nut-tree/nut.js/issues/223 (или шире: https://github.com/nut-tree/nut.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+vundefined).

Comment: @nörbörnën, допустим.. Если я буду упаковывать свое приложение, значит на другом компьютере тоже же будет зависимость от питона?

Comment: нет, там будут биндинги модулей. т.е. если на другой машине ты будешь запускать как `node ./index.html` - 99%, что нужен будет питон. а вот под электроном нет

Comment: То есть это нужно будет только мне?

Comment: да, только на стороне разработчика

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, спасибо за issues, откатился до 6.14.13 версии npm и вроде установилось. Будем тестить)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, nut.js не работает с русским текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Не ответ, а скорее тест.

> Из коммента
> nut.js не работает с русским текстом

Если научить, вышеуказанные пакеты, переключать раскладку и вводить латиницу(либо коды клавиш), вполне даже печатает.

В самом простом варианте, создаем карту `RU->EN` и подменяем символы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Определить язык раскладки, можно пакетом [keyboard-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keyboard-layout). Но мне не удалось запустить пример, когда активен RU. Вероятно класс `Keyboard`, при инициализации, что-то тоже определяет.

Невыполнимый сниппет:

```js
import { keyboard, Key } from "@nut-tree/nut-js"
import { getCurrentKeymap } from 'keyboard-layout'

const keyMap = {
  a: 'ф',
  b: 'и',
  c: 'с',
  d: 'в',
  e: 'у',
  f: 'а',
  g: 'п',
  h: 'р',
  i: 'ш',
  j: 'о',
  k: 'л',
  l: 'д',
  m: 'ь',
  n: 'т',
  o: 'щ',
  p: 'з',
  q: 'й',
  r: 'к',
  s: 'ы',
  t: 'е',
  u: 'г',
  v: 'м',
  w: 'ц',
  x: 'ч',
  y: 'н',
  z: 'я',
  '`': 'ё',
  '[': 'х',
  ']': 'ъ',
  ';': 'ж',
  '\'': 'э',
  ',': 'б',
  '.': 'ю',
  // Этот символ у меня(Num3) неправильно определяется
  '#': '№'
}

const ruMap = Object.entries(keyMap)
  .reduce((a, [key, ru]) => {
    a.set(ru, key)
    return a
  }, new Map())

function isRU() {
  return getCurrentKeymap().KeyA.unmodified === 'ф'
}

const KeyboardLayout = {
  isRu: isRU(),
  // isRu: false,
  isUp: false,
  async invertLang() {
    // Если переключение раскладки [Левый Shift] + [Левый Alt]
    await keyboard.pressKey(Key.LeftShift, Key.LeftAlt)
    await keyboard.releaseKey(Key.LeftShift, Key.LeftAlt)
  },
  async any() {
    if (!this.isRu) return
    this.isRu = false
    await this.invertLang()
  },
  async ru() {
    if (this.isRu) return
    this.isRu = true
    await this.invertLang()
  },
  async upper() {
    if (this.isUp) return
    this.isUp = true
    await keyboard.pressKey(Key.LeftShift)
  },
  async lower() {
    if (!this.isUp) return
    this.isUp = false
    await keyboard.releaseKey(Key.LeftShift)
  }
}

async function print(text) {
  const sequence = []
  const push = (s, lang, up = false) => {
    const ul = up ? 'upper' : 'lower'
    const last = sequence.length ? sequence[sequence.length - 1] : null
    if (last && last[0] === lang && last[1] === ul) {
      last.push(s)
      return
    }
    sequence.push([lang, ul, s])
  }
  // Разбираем символы
  for (let s of [...text]) {
    // а-яё + №
    if (/^[а-яё№]$/.test(s)) {
      push(ruMap.get(s), 'ru')
    } else if (/^[А-ЯЁ]$/.test(s)) {
      push(ruMap.get(s.toLowerCase()), 'ru', true)
    } else {
      push(s, 'any')
    }
  }
  // console.log(sequence)
  // Пишем
  for (let [lang, up, ...txt] of sequence) {
    await KeyboardLayout[lang]()
    await KeyboardLayout[up]()
    await keyboard.type(txt.join(''))
  }
}

keyboard.config.autoDelayMs = 10

// Запускать пример, только при раскладке EN

const exampleText = `// Test:
// Русский текст mixed with English
// \`1234567890-=
// ~!@#$%^&*()_+
// верхний ряд RU => "№;:?
// "небуквенные" => [];'\\,./{}:"|<>? ёхъжэбю. ЁХЪЖЭБЮ,
// end ^)`
print(exampleText)
```

С [robotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs), точно такая история - ввод латиницы с раскладкой RU печатает как и положено.

Comment: invertLang() далеко не универсальным получается ибо клавиши смены можно изменить в системе. А так же, если в системе несколько языков.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Поигрался сегодня с `robotjs`, но печатает долго. Переключение раскладки через `[Win] + [Space]` и проверкой `getCurrentKeyboardLanguage()-keyboard-layout` - в отличии от `@nut-tree/nut-js` запускается из любой раскладки. А с языками, думаю, не все так просто - [в 2017 на Windows Юникод не работал](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/pull/276#issuecomment-331466724). С тех времен почти ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Я так понял, довольно сложно будет это все реализовать нормально? Я делал скрипты на AutoHotKey до этого, но хочу полностью перебраться на ноду, но вот вроде самое базовое и уже затык дикий с языками..